# Trigger and Stored Procedure in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am developing an online airticketing application and backend is in MariaDB database. I have the reservation table with the following structure:

[image: reservation table structure]

When the record is inserted in the reservation_status the default value is TE which means timer expired. In this system I want to give users a 15 minute session time to complete the reservation. If the reservation is complete within 15 minutes of time the value of reservation_status field changes to XE which means successful booking.

I have a next table called schedule which has the following structure:

[image: schedule table structure].

When a record is inserted in the reservation table the value in a row is updated. It means it increments the value of booked field and at the same time it decrements the value of remaining field by the same number.
The problem arises when 15 minutes of time is over and passenger is not able to complete his booking due to any kind of reason. If the booking is not complete within 15 minutes of time i need to decrease the value of booked field and increase the value of the remaining field which was changed when booking process started.
I have no idea how to reverse those values automatically in MariaDB database after the session of 15 minutes booking time is expired for every booking request of the reservation table.

Comment: Transactions come to mind, but if you are going to hold locks for 15 minutes, you better be very careful about deadlocks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 15 minute grace period is rarely implemented via database locks precisely because of increased chance of deadlocks. Application level locks are better suited to this task.

Comment: If you don't expect it to be transactional (given that you can't afford holding locks for 15 min), you can, for example, create a one-time event which would fire in 15 min and would update `schedule` depending on the data in the corresponding row of `reservation`. Or, if the precision of 15 min is not that important (e.g. it can be 950 seconds rather than 900), you can create a permanent event which would fire once a minute, check for expired records in `reservation` and update `schedule` accordingly. Both are rather artificial though, easier done on the application side.

Answer (score 0):

When booking...

```
BEGIN;
increment one thing
decrement the other
record the time in the "job" table
COMMIT;
```

When time has expired...

```
BEGIN;
DEcrement one thing
INcrement the other
remove the item from job table
COMMIT;
```

The "job" table may need more than just a timestamp -- it may need a seat number, room number, or whatever, so you know what to in/decrement.

I would suggest the "job" be a program that continually runs; it wakes up periodically (say, every minute) and checks whether there is something to cleanup.

One more thing, in case the "job" crashes, you need some mechanism, such as a cron job, to perform a "keep-alive" on it.  That launches it, but it is coded to die if it is currently running.